# Modernizr loads but no change in IE8

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I am trying to add Modernizr into my wordpress installation. I do that by adding the following line, just after wp_head(); in the header:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
```

According to firebug the script is loaded, but the script doesn't seem to have effect in IE8.

I've added the following line into my css:

```
.borderradius body {
  background: #c00;
}
```

In firefox the background turns red, in IE8 nothing happens.

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section are set on display: block;

What else could I possibly do to get it working in IE8?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: IE 8 does not support `border-radius` – so your _expectation_ that modernizer should add a class saying it would is _wrong_. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13289360/1427878

Comment: Right, my expectation that modernizr would in some magical way make css3 properties work was wrong indeed. I also suspected media query's to work with the use of modernizr (my complete layout changed dramaticly with testing in IE, so my first thought was I needed modernizr, the actual reason for this post), but that doesn't seem to be the case so I will continue my research. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I completely forgot to added support for media query's, so I've added mediaqueries.js and now it's already far better ;)

Comment: Correct, modernizer’s job is only to tell you what a browser _supports_, so that you can react to that. To implement functionality that is not given in a specific browser (/version), you need to look into what’s called “polyfills”. (Those are mostly available for JS features, but some for CSS as well.) And `border-radius` is not an essential feature in most cases, but if you absolutely want to have it in IE 8 as well, look f.e. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830372/how-to-apply-border-radius-in-ie8-and-below-ie8-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [HTML Shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) to get HTML5 elements to work in <=IE8. Include that script before any others, preferably in your `<head>`. The next one you'll need is a media query/matchMedia polyfill, which mediaqueries.js will work fine, I've also had luck with [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). Lastly if you want CSS3 support for things like border-radius, you'll need a polyfill like [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/), including the .HTC file it comes with for legacy IE support.

Here's an example of my starter boilerplate `<head>`, which is heavily based on HTML5 Boilerplate (it doesn't including CSS3 Pie):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/screen.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will definitely give css3 pie a try as well.